# finding bi-directional connections in a table

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL result set (as result of a join FWIW):

```
A,C
B,E
C,A
D,A
```

Every value represents a node. So the total set of nodes involved is A,B,C,D,E. Every row describes a directed edge.

```
A -> C
B -> E
C -> A
D -> A
```

Of course this can be simplified to

```
A <-> C
B -> E
D -> A
```

Now I would like to filter out the rows that do not have a bi-directional counterpart. So the final result set should be

```
A,C
C,A
```

or

```
A,C
```

in this case.

I am looking the best way to express this in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine a table Nodes with columns Node1 and Node2.

```
SELECT node1, node2
FROM nodes n
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM nodes WHERE node1 = n.node2 AND node2 = n.node1)
```

Of course you'll want to make sure its appropriate indexed, namely:

```
(node1, node2)
```

and

```
(node2, node1)
```

This will still get you A,C and C,A.  To filter those out change the query to:

```
SELECT node1, node2
FROM nodes n
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM nodes WHERE node1 = n.node2 AND node2 = n.node1)
AND node1 < node2
```

assuming there is a natural ordering you can take advantage of.

Comment: 'nodes' is actually a select. So this does seem to work:

select node1, node2 from 
(select ... ) n
where exists (select 1 from 
(select ... ) x
where node1 = n.node2 and node2 = n.node1)

but I am wondering if the database optimizer is really smart enough to execute this efficiently like that.

Comment: You could generate a million rows of test data and try it.  Personally Ithink it'll work just fine (properly indexed).

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Temp table creating to insert example rows
SELECT 
'A' AS Col1, 'C' AS Col2
INTO #TEMP
UNION
SELECT 'B', 'E'
UNION
SELECT 'C', 'A'
UNION
SELECT 'D', 'A'


SELECT A.* FROM #TEMP A, #TEMP B
WHERE (A.COL1 = B.COL2 AND A.COL2 = B.COL1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner-join the node pairs to themself?

```
select node1, node2
from nodes n
inner join nodes n2
on n.node1 = n2.node2 and n.node2 = n2.node1
```

(replace 'nodes' with your subquery)